# Problem related to combination of lens & equivalent focal length and lens maker's formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, lenses

[image: 1 and 2 are equiconvex]

in between two equiconvex lens( made of glass) of focal length of 20cm there is a layer of water which also acts as a convex lens.The whole figure is surrounded by air. Find out it's equivalent focal length.

I and my friends did it in two ways.We both used the lens makers formula to derive the focal length of equiconvex lens and the bi-concave lens. But he counted air as the surrounding layer of bi-concave lens which is made of water and I counted glass as surrounding layer.

which one of us is correct?

This is my first post in this group,so sorry for any kind of inconvenience.